# Plot a histogram using the index as x-axis labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe in python

```
  Sex  Survived
0  female  0.742038
1    male  0.188908
```

i would like to plot a histogram, where male and female are the two values in the x-axis and y axis has its corresponding values. Any idea how ? . I am new to matplotlib and pandas, so please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion you need [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df.plot.bar(x='Sex', y='Survived')
```

[image: graph]

because [`histogram`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) plot distribution of numerical data.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to plot a histogram, as your data is already histogrammed. Instead you want to plot a simple bar plot.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u = u"""Sex Survived
female 0.742038
male 0.188908"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), delim_whitespace=True)

df.plot.bar(x="Sex", y="Survived")

plt.show()
```

[image]